# Fancy box popup is not working

Tags: c#-4.0

I created a web application where it needs to popup images and videos from Fancy boxes called rippolls. Here my "Rippolls" are load in popup boxes and users can vote for those rippolls.
My  question is, in one page I listed all rippolls and when I click on a rippoll with an image or video it is loaded withour fancy box and fancy box css.

I have referenced

```
 <script src="../../Content/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/Styles/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in a _layout.cshtml where is referenced to the _RippollList.chtml page.
Code in the _RippollList.chtml is :

```
$("a.btnVotePop@(poll.Id)").fancybox({

        'onComplete' : function() {
                  alert('hello');
                 try {
                  FB.XFBML.parse();
                  twttr.widgets.load();
                  history.pushState({}, "@poll.Name.Trim()", "/polls/@poll.Id");
                  document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "@poll.Name.Trim()";
                  //history.replaceState({}, "title", "@poll.Name.Trim()");
                  //$("#rippoll_image_path").attr("content", $("#polltitle").val());
                  }
                  catch (ex) {
                        alert('Error parsing response.');
                  }

            },

            'onClosed' : function(){
                 alert("closed");
                try {
                history.pushState({}, "Rippoll", "/home/mypage");
                document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "My Page";
                 $('#divDetailCont').css('display', 'none');
                }
                catch (ex) {

                }
            },  

             ajax : {
                 type   : "GET"
             },

            'width': '560px'         

    });
```

*Html :*

```
<div id="videoDeftImgContainer" class="videoDefultImg">
<a class="btnVotePop@(poll.Id)" href="RippollCardPopup/@(poll.Id)">
<img class="inImgSize" src="@poll.ImagePath" />
</a>
<div id="plyBtnClk" class="playBtn" onclick="">
 <a class="btnVotePop@(poll.Id)" href="RippollCardPopup/@(poll.Id)">
<img src="../../Content/images/newImages/hoverPlay.png" />
</a></div></div>
```

*script references:*

```
 <script src="../../Content/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/Styles/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but still I m getting a page without fancybox and its styles.

I am in a doubt of because I am putting some text values to rippoll( ex: rippoll name, rippoll question etc..) and it may having some special characters(@%$#{}) also, and is it the reason for not open rippolls in the fancy box.

Help me out for this. please post if any code segments where you successed.